# tabbed layout inside fragment not working properly

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i'm a beginner trying to apply the idea of having tabbed layout inside a "main" fragment that allows me to navigate to other "secondary fragments" as well, there is a main activity with a button which when clicked will inflate the tabbed fragment inside this activity.
but what i got is this: the tabs are duplicated on just the first fragment for some reason.

[image]
[image]

here is my code: MainActiviy.java

```
public class MainActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void fragny(View view) {
    FragmentTransaction ft=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.ma,new labRatFrag());
    ft.commit();
}
```

}
main_activity.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/ma"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:onClick="fragny"
    />
```

FragmentPagerAdapter

```
public class FragAdapt extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private static final String[] TAB_TITLES = new String[]{"test1","test2","test3"};
    private final Context mContext;

    public FragAdapt(Context context ,FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mContext=context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new labRatFrag();
            case 1:
                return new labRatFrag2();
            case 2:
                return new labRatFrag3();
            default:
                    return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getPageTitle(int position) {
        return TAB_TITLES[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

my main fragment (labRatFrag.java)

```
public class labRatFrag extends Fragment {


public labRatFrag() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lab_rat, container, false);

    FragAdapt fa=new FragAdapt(getContext(),getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    ViewPager vp=v.findViewById(R.id.pagery);
    vp.setAdapter(fa);
    TabLayout tabs = v.findViewById(R.id.toto);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(vp);

    return v;
}
```

}

fragment_lab_rat.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        >
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/toto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pagery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

i want to do this in order to apply this idea with bottom navigation or navigation drawer for a future app i'm planning

Comment: use different `FragmentManager` for both containers. The issue is because you are using same `FragmentManager`.

Comment: how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

`FragAdapt` is for your secondary fragment, right?

if yes, try replacing

`FragAdapt fa=new FragAdapt(getContext(),getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());`

with

`FragAdapt fa=new FragAdapt(getContext(),getChildFragmentManager());`.

It might help. If not, will prepare a demo for you

Comment: i replaced it like you said but now when i click the button nothing happens and the app freezes (no run terminal msg)